# Creating an Array2D from the value counts of two distinct arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#

I am having problems getting this code correct.  The result of the Contour variable should be an Array2D 64x64 containing data for a contour of arr1 by arr2.  I made the two arrays random for the example.  The syntax error says the block following the last let is unfinished.

```
type System.Random with
    /// Generates an infinite sequence of random numbers within the given range.
    member this.GetValues(minValue, maxValue) =
        Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> this.Next(minValue, maxValue))

let cnt = 10000
let r = System.Random()
let arr1 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt
let arr2 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt

let datareso = 262144
let dispreso = 64
let bucketsiz = datareso / dispreso

let Contour = 
        let dat = Array2D.init dispreso dispreso (fun i j -> 0)
        for idx in 0 .. cnt-1 do
            let x = System.Math.Round(arr1.[idx] / bucketsiz)
            let y = System.Math.Round(arr2.[idx] / bucketsiz)
                       dat.[x, y] + 1
        dat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the error you're getting, I see a few other beginner mistakes in your code. I'll list them all for you.

First, you're creating two sequences named `arr1` and `arr2` and, later, accessing them by index in a loop. I strongly suspect that you meant them to be arrays, because accessing a sequence by index is an O(N) operation, whereas accessing an array index is O(1). So your loop is O(N^2) at the moment, and it should be O(N). To fix this, add a call to `Array.ofSeq` after the `Seq.take cnt` when you create `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
let arr1 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt |> Array.ofSeq
let arr2 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt |> Array.ofSeq
```

Second, you're creating the array by calling `Array2D.init` with an initialization function that always returns 0. There's a MUCH faster way to do this: call [`Array2D.zeroCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array2d.zerocreate%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d). Using `Array2D.init` will call your function `dispreso * dispreso` times, whereas `Array2D.zeroCreate` will eliminate all of those function calls. Any time you want to initialize an array to zero (or to the default value of whatever type is in the array), always use the `zeroCreate` function as it's by far the most efficient.

Next, this line doesn't do anything:

```
dat.[x, y] + 1
```

What you want to do, I assume, is increment the value stored in the 2D array at position `x, y`. But what that line does is retrieve the value and add 1 to it, and produce a result that is thrown away because it's not stored anywhere or used in any calculations. (You probably have a compiler warning about that line saying something like "This value is effectively ignored" and telling you to fix it). What you wanted was to store that value back into the array, like so:

```
dat.[x, y] <- dat.[x, y] + 1
```

Finally, the cause of your "unfinished block" error is that the `dat.[x, y] + 1` line is indented too far, so there's no statement immediately after the `let y = ...` line. That's a syntax error in F#: there should always be something following a `let` statement. Simply dedenting the `dat.[x, y] + 1` line would give you the right results.

Here's your code with all these errors corrected:

```
type System.Random with
    /// Generates an infinite sequence of random numbers within the given range.
    member this.GetValues(minValue, maxValue) =
        Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> this.Next(minValue, maxValue))

let cnt = 10000
let r = System.Random()
let arr1 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt |> Array.ofSeq
let arr2 = r.GetValues(1, 262144) |> Seq.take cnt |> Array.ofSeq

let datareso = 262144
let dispreso = 64
let bucketsiz = datareso / dispreso

let Contour = 
        let dat = Array2D.zeroCreate dispreso dispreso
        for idx in 0 .. cnt-1 do
            let x = System.Math.Round(arr1.[idx] / bucketsiz)
            let y = System.Math.Round(arr2.[idx] / bucketsiz)
            dat.[x, y] <- dat.[x, y] + 1
        dat
```

Comment: A huge thanks for the insight rmunn.  I still got an error with the Round function, so changed it to "int" to force an integer.  Works like a charm.  I thought I might have to make the "dat" array mutable, but no.

Comment: One point that often trips up F# beginners is what `let mutable someVar = ...` means. It *only* means that you can now do `someVar <- someNewValue`. The inherent, *internal* mutability of `someVar` has not been changed. In particular, F# lists are internally immutable, and doing `let mutable lst = [1; 2; 3]` does not suddenly let you write `lst.[1] <- 999`. Since F# arrays are the same type as C# arrays, they are internally mutable (that is, `arr.[1] <- 999` is legal) without needing to use the `mutable` keyword.

Comment: To demonstrate what I mean regarding mutable lists, try doing `let mutable lst = [2; 3]`. Then `let lstCopy = lst`. Now do `lst <- 1 :: lst`, then do `printfn "%A" lst` and `printfn "%A" lstCopy`. You'll notice that `lst` contains `[1; 2; 3]` while `lstCopy` contains `[2; 3]`. The reason is that `lstCopy` was assigned to point to the contents of `lst` at the time that assignment happened; at the time, `lst` contained `[2; 3]`. When you did `lst <- 1 :: lst`, that changed *which list `lst` was pointing to*, but it did not change the *contents* of the list `[2; 3]`.

Comment: You are correct, I did not know that about mutable variables.  And most tutorials I watch and read don't point that out.  Thanks.

Comment: Something I missed earlier: you don't need `System.Math.Round` or `int` here. Both `arr1.[idx]` and `bucketsiz` are integers, so you're dividing an integer by an integer. In F#, that produces an integer with the remainder thrown away. So you can remove `System.Math.Round` entirely. (Also, that's why you were getting an error: `System.Math.Round` expects a float, but you were passing it an int — and F# is strict about types and deliberately does not do numeric auto-conversions that other languages do, such as int to float.)

Answer (score 0):

By this line:

```
    dat.[x, y] + 1
```

did you mean something more like this:

```
    dat.[x, y] <- dat.[x, y] + 1
```

I notice that there is a strange initial space in your text in that line.